# Creating a BarChart with scala.js

Tags: d3.js, scala.js

I am trying to create a Bar Chart using [scala-js-d3](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3).

The problem is that in the title there is no and only the underline is visible. Bars have no text at all.

The BarChart is rendered and there are no problems in the console of Developer Tools.

Here is a sample of the code used:

```
val graphHeight = 450

    //The width of each bar.
    val barWidth = 80

    //The distance between each bar.
    val barSeparation = 10


    //The actual horizontal distance from drawing one bar rectangle to drawing the next.
    val horizontalBarDistance = barWidth + barSeparation

    //The value to multiply each bar's value by to get its height.
    val barHeightMultiplier = graphHeight / maxData;

    //Color for start
    val color = d3.rgb("DarkSlateBlue")

    //val my_data = js.Array(8, 22, 31, 36, 48, 17, 25)

    val rectXFun = (d: Int, i: Int) => i * horizontalBarDistance
    val rectYFun = (d: Int) => graphHeight - d * barHeightMultiplier

    val rectXFun2 = (d: Int, i: Int) => i * horizontalBarDistance +5
    val rectYFun2 = (d: Int) => graphHeight - d * barHeightMultiplier +15
    val rectHeightFun = (d: Int) => d * barHeightMultiplier
    val rectColorFun = (d: Int, i: Int) => color.brighter(i * 0.5).toString
    val remove_element = d3.select("#"+currContainer).select("svg").remove()
    val svg = d3.select("#"+currContainer).append("svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "450px")
    val sel = svg.selectAll("rect").data(my_data)
    val data_enter = sel.enter()
    val sel2 = data_enter
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", rectXFun)
      .attr("y", rectYFun)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .attr("height", rectHeightFun)
      .style("fill", rectColorFun)
    //.style("fill", "black")

      val textXOffset = horizontalBarDistance / 2 - 12
      val textYOffset = 20
      val textYPosition = graphHeight + textYOffset;

      //Draw the text.
      data_enter.append("text").text((d: Int) => d.toString)
      .attr("x", (d: Int,i: Int) => i * horizontalBarDistance + textXOffset)
      .attr("y", textYPosition)
      .style("text-decoration", "underline")
      .style("fill","black")
      .style("font-size", "16px")

      svg.append("text")
      //.attr("x", (width / 2))
      //.attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .text("Graph Title")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "16px")
      .style("text-decoration", "underline")
      .style("fill","blue")
      .style("color","blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the axis for the example to work.